# Is it possible to Integrate a SecuGen Hamster pro 20 with ReactJs

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, fingerprint

I'm developing a Fingerprint voting system WebApp using ReactJS for the frontend and Java with Spring Boot for the backend. I've completed the backend functionality in Java and now need assistance with integrating a SecuGen Hamster Pro 20 fingerprint scanner with ReactJS. The scanner's documentation lacks information on this integration. Can someone provide guidance on how to integrate the SecuGen Hamster Pro 20 fingerprint scanner with ReactJS for sending fingerprint data to the database?

Their WebApi documentation contains mostly libraries for Aspnet or maybe i'm not just understanding the documentation.